# Max value for compareTo() method

Tags: java, sorting

I want to implement merge sort but I need in this case max value for guard. I tired use null as max value but I get null pointer exception.

```
 private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge(T[] A, int p, int q, int r) {

        T[] L = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, p, q + 1);
        T[] R = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, q, r + 1);


        L[L.length - 1] = null; //guard
        R[R.length - 1] = null; //guard


        int i = 0; 
        int j = 0; 
        // i+j < r - k
        for (int k = p; k < r; k++) {            
            if (L[i].compareTo(R[j]) <= 0) {
                A[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                A[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

so I defined

```
Comparable<T> guard = new Comparable<T>(){

    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return 1; //always max
    }};

    L[L.length - 1] = (T) guard;
    R[R.length - 1] = (T) guard;
```

but if I use it as guard instead of null I can rewrite the code but I get always ArrayStoreException

how to do in right way?

So question is:
  how to define object which is comparability with T type without knowing what is T.

Comment: “how to do in right way?” Well, the right way is to implement an algorithm which doesn’t need such a guard.

Comment: I think you need to provide an SSCCE so people can run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use null, instead use -1 if you are sorting positive values or very large values

Instead of

```
    L[L.length - 1] = null; //guard
    R[R.length - 1] = null; //guard
```

Use

```
    L[L.length - 1] = -1; //guard
    R[R.length - 1] = -1; //guard
```

Comment: In case when I have a numbers I can do that but when I will have any type of object with implements Comparable interface?
  

I cannot put -1 in to T type.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the comparator which always returns 1 is bad idea, it doesn't confirm to comparator requirements.

You always know where the guard is so you may check indices or you may check for null. So just add special logic which will bypass comparator if element is a guard.
Something like this:

```
 for (int k = p; k < r; k++) {            
      if (R[j] == null || (L[i] != null && L[i].compareTo(R[j]) <= 0)) {
          A[k] = L[i];
          i++;
      }
      else {
          A[k] = R[j];
          j++;
      }
 }
```

Comment: This is not a comparator!

Comment: Way do you think that definition of object which is always bigger (compareTo returns 1) is a bad idea?

Comment: Because it breaks comparatTo contract. This should always be true `yourFakeComparator.compareTo(yourFakeComparator) == 0`.